# Get url of a hyperlink inside webview to a textview

Tags: c#, xamarin, webview, hyperlink, xamarin.forms

I have a webview in my app using xamarin forms(C#).

I load a html(byte array by webclient.download)to webview.

Q:How to get the url of a hyperlink to a textview when cliclek instead of navigate to the web?

hyperlink clicked -> url of hyperlink in text view and webview remain the same page

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

There is a navigation event on WebView that you can subscribe.

From code:

```
webView.Navigating += (s, e) => { 
   // do something with e.Url
}
```

From XAML:

```
Navigating="onNavigating"


void onNavigating (object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    // do something with e.Url
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. Although I did find an answer. Still appreciate ur help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
      webpage.Navigating += (object sender2, WebNavigatingEventArgs ev) => {
                int k = 0;
                if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(ev.Url, UriKind.Absolute))
                {
                    urltext.Text = ev.Url;
                    ev.Cancel = true;
                }
            };
```

ev.Url for getting url inside text(Entry)

ev.Cancel for stop webview from navigating to ohter website but clicking hyperlink